# Restrict a visitor submit the form if it was already submitted by him

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, cookies

I want to restrict a visitor to submit the form more than once, and the only way of doing that, as I think, is cookies. In my controller I create a cookie:

```
class RatingsController < ApplicationController
  require 'securerandom'
  before_action :session_cookie

  def create
    @rating = Rating.new(rating_params)
    @rating.save
    render json: { rating: @rating.casino.average_rating.to_f.round(2) }, status: 200
  end

  private

  def rating_params
    params.require(:rating).permit(:score, :casino_id)
  end

  def session_cookie
    cookies[:name] = { value: SecureRandom.base64, expires: Time.now + 3600}
  end

end
```

The form, I'm using - is submitting by clicking on a star(it's a 5 star rating, and I use `ajax` to submit it). And now, how to restrict a visitor to submit the form again, using that cookie? The first idea was to add a column to db and save a cookie there, and then use validation, to check uniqueness of cookie, but I don't know, if this is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of using cookies to make that kind of validation is that the user if he/she really wants to vote again he could reset the cookies on his computer, or even if your user has voted a week ago and dont remember that he voted and he is on another browser he wont see his vote.

So assuming you have users, i mean they are logged in and you have access to the user, you could create a new model called usersVote, so you would store the user id and the casino_id and the score, it would be something like this.

```
class CreateUsersVote < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def up
        create_table :users_vote do |t|
            t.integer 'score', null:false
            t.references :user, null:false
            t.references :casino, null:false
        end
    end

    def down
        drop_table :users_vote
    end
end
```

So if the user submited again from whatever computer he is in, you would be take care of that.

EDIT: So if there is no user the only way to validate that user would be using cookies like you said, but you would not need to involve rails or the database to this task, since you wont be able to validate anything if the user change his cookies like i said above, so the way you would do this is only using jquery:

```
$.cookie("userHasVoted", 1, { expires : 10 });
//10 is the number of days when the cookie will expire
```

you would put that on your ajax submission and if the user submit again you would prevent him from submiting:

```
if($.cookie("userHasVoted") == 1) {
    alert("You have submited already");
    //prevent user from submiting
}
```

Comment: The app doesn't have users, that are able to sign in.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do this is to add a boolean column `submitted` on your `ratings` table

**migraion**

```
add_column :ratings, :submitted, :boolean, :default => false
```

run `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

then in your `Rating` model

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base

    def submitted!
        self.submitted = true
        self.save
    end

end
```

Then, in your AJAX controller action, you can do something like

```
class RatingsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @rating = Rating.new(rating_params)
    if @rating.save
        @rating.submitted!
        render json: { rating: @rating.casino.average_rating.to_f.round(2), submitted: true }, status: 200
    else
        render json: { errors: @rating.errors }, status: 422
    end
  end

end
```

Then on your AJAX success block, you can

```
success: function(res, status, xhr) {
    if (res.submitted == true) {
        // hide or disable the button on your UI with jQuery/JS
    }
}
```

This way, the form submission is not only persisted for that AJAX call but also maintained in your database.
Next time the user visits this page to re-submit, you can pull the user's rating from the db and check the `submitted` flag if the user has already submitted or not to use it in your view file to add a `if` block to hide the button.